# Why can't exported types be found?

Tags: typescript, webpack

We’re seeing a lot of these warnings during our build:

```
WARNING in ./src/models/index.ts 32:0-112
export 'ReviewOfSystem' (reexported as 'ReviewOfSystem') was not found in './VisitDocumentation' (possible exports: ImmunizationStatus, VisitDocumentation)
 @ ./src/components/apps/PrivateApp.tsx 30:0-39 53:25-42 76:26-42 81:29-43 87:43-60 147:40-56 150:31-45 173:125-139
 @ ./src/components/apps/App.tsx 7:0-42 59:32-42
 @ ./src/index.tsx 59:0-44 218:80-83
```

`ReviewOfSystem` is an exported type. `Immunization` and `VisitDocumentation` are classes.

We started seeing these warnings yesterday when I updated the `target` in our `tsconfig.json` file from `"commonjs"` to `"esnext"`. I made that change to support code-splitting on dynamic imports.

We use the `ts-loader` loader with `transpileOnly` set to `true` so that incremental builds by the webpack dev server are faster. We use the `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin` to do type checking

Does anyone know where these warnings are coming from and how to resolve them?

I know they are warnings and could be ignored, but ignored warnings tend to become subtle bugs in production systems, in my experience.

Comment: It seems like this is a known issue and the only solution is to disable the warnings.  See Loader Options at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader?activeTab=readme.

Answer (score 0):

As ReviewOfSystem is exported as type,
You need also add type when Importing it.

Something like

```
import type { ReviewOfSystem } from 'bla-bla'
```

You can refer this official doc from typescript :
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html